# What is the difference between [ngIf] and *ngIf in angular?

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have used below 2line of codes in component, both are working as expected,
but why we have 2 different type of directive.
please help me to understand below code.

show content
show content

Answer (score -1):

They are the same exact thing. One is just newer syntax and that is *ngfor